# Gitlab runner conditional run depending on commit message

Tags: git, git-commit, git-push, gitlab-ci

I have been using Gitlab for a while and now set up a build server. As I change machines (Notebook/PC) I often commit and push to save my work to my gitlab server as the contents are regularly backed up to the cloud.

The build server, works great but the complete project is build on every push. As its quite a big one, I would like to do something like this:

- Push commits with comment "release 1.2.3.4"  - >  Gitlab triggers the
  build
- All other pushes of commits are ignored by the runner.

It is ok if only the head commit comment ist checked on build.

I searched the .gitlab.yml documentation but could not find anything helpful.

Comment: If a commit was only a readme change, for example, you can write `[skip ci]` or `[ci skip]` in your git commit message -- I tried to find this in the docs and wasn't able to locate it.    If your push only contains commits that have this skip marker, CI builds will be skipped.

Comment: Also it's time to think about breaking your project up into multiple git repos and multiple CI targets (build_x, build_y, build_z where x and y and z are built separately, and you can parellelize your pipelines). And you might want to think about using Caching so that incremental builds become possible.   Caching can save a lot of time in C/C++, Java, and other compiled language builds where incremental building saves time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your example message "release 1.2.3.4", the best approach is to restrict the build to tagged commits only.

In your exinsting `gitlab-ci.yml` file, add the "only" attribute to the end of the step you want to restrict.

```
job1:
  stage: build
script:
- echo "building..."
# - Your commands here
only:
- tags
```

Now, every time you need to build it, just tag the commit using:

```
git tag "release 1.2.3.4"
```

If you really need to see every commit the message you should look in the [CI Variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/README.html), there's a way to get the current commit hash ref.

Comment: Using Tortoise I do net get this up and running. I commit, tag and push but nothing happens, no new pipeline ist started.

Comment: But based on your tip I tried to use "only: - master" an this works! So I will develop in a branch and only merge it to the master on releases. Perhaps the tag thingy does not work due to the way tortoise wraps the git commands. However, I accept your answer as it helped me find a solution,

Comment: Did you pushed the tags as well, after the commits using git push origin --tags? You can it checkout in Gitlab in Repository -> Tags. You can also create tags at this section of the web interface. But anyway, glad I could help.

Comment: I will experiment with tags..  But merging to Master on releases is also ok with me.

Comment: Your answer works perectly. I forgot to tick "Include Tags" in Tortoise-Git. Unfortunately this option is always off be default and has to be ticked manually before pushing. I also included 
 " exclude: 
    - develop 
    - hotfix " in .gitlab-ci.yml to avoid accidentially tagging one of those branches triggering a build. Thanks once more!

Comment: Great! Glad I was able to help you!